# Heatmap using Rbf

Tags: python-3.x, heatmap

I want to make a heatmap. It has x-axis (1-10), y-axis(1-20). But, my CSV file has data at some of the x, and y-axis, which make my heatmap look like a scattered plot. Even I used the Rbf (radial basis function) module to get the values at each co-ordinate. But, it gives me really unexpected results.
If you can help me, please reply. 
Thank you

_______________________________  Data ________________________

X    Y   D

1    3   -2

3    1   -5

5    2   -9

________________________________ Code ________________________

```
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sea

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

get = pd.read_csv('small.csv',',')

D = pd.pivot_table(get, values = 'D', index = 'X', columns = 'Y')

sea.heatmap(data = D, vmin = -10, vmax = 0, cmap = 'BuPu')

plt.show()
```

__________________________output__________________________________

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZkq6.png)

Comment: Please add some of your code, data and etc for helping others to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Novonimo, I added more information. I want to get the full heatmap for the x-axis (1 to 5) and y-axis (1-3). so, for that what should I have to do.
Thank you